# General Solution to this system of differential equations

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

The question asks for me to find the general solution to this problem

$X'= \left( \begin{array}{cc}
1 & 0 & 0\\
2 & 2 & -1\\
0 & 1 & 0
\end{array} \right)X$

I said the general solution was $C_1(0,1,1)e^t+C_2(0,1,0)e^t+C_3(1/2,0,0)e^t$ and apparently I was wrong. I think the eigenvectors I have are correct and I'm also pretty sure the eigenvalues are correct.

Does anyone see what I did wrong here?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: You don’t really need to find eigenvectors, generalized or otherwise. Decompose the matrix into the sum of a diagonal matrix $\lambda I$ and nilpotent matrix $N$ and use the fact that the series expansion of $e^{tN}$ has only finitely many terms.

Answer (score 0):

Your solution would be correct were the matrix diagonalizable, but it’s not. Let’s check: Since the three vectors you’ve got are linearly independent, your solution simplifies to $e^t\,X_0$, where $X_0$ is an arbitrary constant vector. This function is its own derivative, so it clearly doesn’t satisfy the differential equation.

What went wrong? $(0,1,1)^T$ is indeed an eigenvector, but the other two vectors that you’ve listed aren’t—they’re *generalized* eigenvectors, which is an important distinction. Although they’re linearly independent, the *functions* that you generated with them aren’t. The correct solution will involve terms in $te^t$ and $t^2e^t$ as well.

It’s possible, and I think a bit less work, to solve this without computing any of the generalized eigenvectors. We know from trying to compute the eigensystem that the system has eigenvalue $1$ with algebraic multiplicity 3 but geometric multiplicity 1. Calling the coefficient matrix $A$, we know from the Cayley-Hamilton theorem that $(A-\lambda I)^3=0$, i.e., that $N=A-\lambda I$ is nilpotent. Moreover, from the information we have about the eigenvalue, the minimal polynomial of $A$ is also $(\lambda-1)^3$, so $N^2\ne0$. Since a multiple of the identity matrix commutes with everything, we have $$e^{tA}=e^t(\lambda I+N)=e^{t\lambda I}e^{tN} = e^{\lambda t}e^{tN}.$$ We also have $$e^{tN} = I+tN+{t^2\over2!}N^2+{t^3\over3!}N^3+\cdots = I+tN+{t^2\over2!}N^2$$ because $N^3=0$. Thus, the solution to the system is $e^t(I+tN+tN^2)\,\mathbf x_0$, where the constant vector $x_0$ is determined by the initial conditions.

For this problem, $$N=\begin{bmatrix}0&0&0\\2&1&-1\\0&1&-1\end{bmatrix}$$ and $$N^2=\begin{bmatrix}0&0&0\\2&0&0\\2&0&0\end{bmatrix},$$ so the general solution is $$e^t\begin{bmatrix}1&0&0\\2t+t^2&1+t&-t\\t^2&t&1-t\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}C_1\\C_2\\C_3\end{bmatrix}.$$ This can be rearranged into a form more like the one you’re used to by a suitable renaming of the constants.